# one-to-one hashes in python

Tags: python, hash

If I have two strings that are identical in value, is it guaranteed that `hash(s1) == hash(s2)` without using `hashlib`? Also, what is the upper bound on the number of digits in the hash? 
Is there an alternative to `hash` that is invertable? I understand hash functions are not meant to be used like this. But a 1-1 mapping from strings to short hexadecimal strings that can be inverted and is guaranteed to be different for each string?

Will this work:

```
import zlib
# compress
zlib.compress("foo")
zlib.decompress(zlib.compress("foo")) == "foo"  # always true?
```

Thanks.

Comment: If a function gives two different outputs for the same input, it can't rightly be called a hash in general, really.

Comment: Yes! What else could hash  be?

Comment: 1. That's kind of the point of hashing. 2. At a guess, whatever fits into an `int`, so `[-sys.maxint-1, sys.maxint]`

Comment: Using `zlib` that way will work, yes. But keep in mind, for such a short input... `len(zlib.compress('foo')) == 11`. Not a big savings! ;). Data compression takes advantage of redundancies in your data, which there won't be many for very short data.

Comment: so what's the best way to get a short (e.g. less than 50 characters) encoding for short strings ranging from 100-300 chars? huffman?

Comment: It would not be a function either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

YES.

```
>>>help(hash)
    Help on built-in function hash in module builtins:

    hash(...)
        hash(object) -> integer

        Return a hash value for the object.  Two objects with the same value have
        the same hash value.  The reverse is not necessarily true, but likely.
```

Comment: How do I get the original string back? i.e. `f(hash("foo")) == "foo"`

Comment: you don't. That's sort of the _purpose_ of a hash function.

Comment: I'm looking for an invertable hashing function should have made it more clear. Simple short mapping from strings to short hexadecimal strings that can be inverted such that two strings with same value have the same hash value

Comment: @user248237 value retured by `hash()` depends on the platform, it's means for a particular string two systems might have different hash() values, so there's no way of getting the original string back.